# What is the meaning of "K-rational Points of elliptic curves of order r", where $K=\mathbb F_p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, affine-varieties

The Paper [1] says in definition 2.1

> suppose E has a K-rational point of order r

Lets assume $K=\mathbb F_p$ for any prime $p$. For this case I could consider the r-Torsion group on E, say $T_{r,E}:=\{P\in E\ \mid\ rP=\mathcal O\}$, then I guess, the set of K-rational points with order r on E is equal to $T_{r,E}$. Am I right or completely wrong?

I guess the right point to start with, is [2] (and a bid up the general definition). Consider $y^2=f(x)$ defines an elliptic curve. Then the definitions says: The $K$-rational Points of E is defined as the set $R:=\{(x,y)\in K^2\ \mid\ f(x)=0\}$. That means, any point on the curve, reduced to $K$ is a $K$-rational point. If I consider the case of "degree r", it turns out, that the set is equal to $\{P\in R\ \mid rP=\mathcal O\}$. Which is the origin of the  r-Torsion subgroup of E. (This is what I guess to be right with.)

## References

[1] http://theory.stanford.edu/~dfreeman/papers/taxonomy.pdf

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_point#Genus_1

Comment: The set of those elements with order $r$ is not the same as the $r$-torsion subgroup, since that will also contain all elements with orders dividing $r$. Other than that they are the same.

Comment: Ok. So such points are a subset?
If I consider $r$ to be prime, this should lead to a equation?

Comment: Hm.. if I add "Any $P\in T_{r,E}$ with $\gcd(ord(P), r)=r$ (no common divisior less than $r$) is called r-rational point." that shall be right?

Comment: Now you are mixing terminology. $K$-rational refers to which field the point is defined over, while the $r$ was the order of said point.

Comment: @.@ you are right.. it seems like I'm a bid confused/dizzy. Its intention was "K-rational"..

Comment: Let $E = \{ (x,y) \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}^2, y^2 = x^3+a x+b\} \cup \{\mathcal{O}\}$. You define its group law. Then you will consider two kind of subgroups : $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^k}) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{F}_{p^k}, y^2 = x^3+a x+b\}\cup \{\mathcal{O}\}$ and $E[l] = \{ P \in E, [l] P = \mathcal{O}\}$. The main problem is to find the number of point and the structure of those groups. The set of degree $r$ and "$\mathbb{F}_p$ rational" points is $E[r] \cap E(\mathbb{F}_p)$.